# Website loader engine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very simple question. I am starter at website building. So I have to build an website with several menus and pages. I have a dropdown menu with 5 main menu items and each main menu has about six sub-menu items. Content of each sub menu items is in html files in diferrent directories.
I look for a content loader engine. I have already try some ajax loader script with repairing bookmarking and back button, but none of them works perfectly. So I need a perfect html and php page loader method which can load content from html or php files when I click on one of menu items.
Thanks!

Regards,
Norbi

Comment: `<a href="url_of_page">link</a>`

Comment: you should make some research about the term "single page application" its ad/disadvantages and best practices

Comment: @johnSmith that's the question - does he really want a "single page website"? if he is so new to it, maybe Quentin's suggestion would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Give a a href link tag for each menu item

```
<a href="path/director/name.extn"> Menu Item 1 </a>
<a href="path/director/name.extn"> Menu Item 2 </a>
```

Will work